# Javascript how to get the value of a parent node

Tags: javascript

hello in the colde below i am trying to get the value of the third span from the img tag

here is the code :

```
<li class="art1">
        <div class="infoArt">
            <div class="infoArtTitle"><a name="3224502"></a>Chemise ML rose clair coupe droite motif bicolore</div>
            <div class="infoArtPrice">
               <br>
                <span id="ctl00_mainColumnContent_universeCatalog_rptCatalog_ctl00_lblP" class="artP">39</span><br>
                <span id="ctl00_mainColumnContent_universeCatalog_rptCatalog_ctl00_lblRetailerPrice" class="artOldP">90</span><br>
                <span id="ctl00_mainColumnContent_universeCatalog_rptCatalog_ctl00_lblAvailability" class="artState">out</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imgArt">
        <div class="infoWrapper" id="n3224502"><!-- id is new new for mdr -->

        </div>
                <a href="/vp4/_sales/ha/bufi/FR_0XQNB3L041/ikId3224502.aspx">
                    <img src="/vp4/_sales/ha/products/ev_3224502.jpg" alt="" style="">
                </a>
        </div>
        <div class="btArt">
            <a class="btSheetPdt" href="/vp4/_sales/ha/bufi/FR_0XQNB3L041/ikId3224502.aspx" title="fiche produit">
                <span>fiche produit</span>
            </a>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>             
        </div>
    </li>
```

I would like to get it from this query to get the **out** value :

`document.getElementsByTagName('img")[0]`

then I have no idea what I should do , could you please help.

Thanks.

Comment: `var el = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];` `var parent = el.parentNode;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the third span from the img by:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.getElementsByTagName("span")[2].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ID of the element:

`document.getElementById("ctl00_mainColumnContent_universeCatalog_rptCatalog_ctl00_lblAvailability")[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The Span is not inside the img tag in your case. If you're looking for the third span, you can try this

```
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[2].innerHTML
```